# xt:commerce a plugin to display box

Tags: php, plugins, box

I am trying to implement a xt:commerce plugin that displays a "box" at the frontend, here my structure:

-> the php data here "plugins/xt_test/boxes/xt_test.php" contains:

```
defined('_VALID_CALL') or die('Direct Access is not allowed.');

if ($params['box_id']) {
    $show_box = true;
} else {
    $show_box = false;
}
```

-> the template "plugins/xt_test/templates/box_xt_test.html" contains a simple

```
<div> test box </div>
```

Nothing is displayed in my shop therefore I am wondering if I am missing something? or perhaps I need to set up something specific in the "install" document? thank you very much in advance.